# Regex that validates all scenarios

Tags: java, regex

I am in the process of writing a regular expression in java that matches the below stuffs and does not match the invalid strings. I am not able to filter it correctly so that it matches only the valid list and not match the invalid one.

here is my regular expression - `(?!\!)([\(\)XSAa\\\#\+\-\s\.\!])+)`

valid strings -

> "A\\#A\\#A\\#","+\#\#\#","(\\#\\#\\#) \\#\\#\\#-\\#\\#\\#\\#","\#\#\#.\#\#\#.\#\#\#\#","!\#\#","X-\#\#\#\#"," \#\#\#\#\#-SSSS","Aaaaa!!"`

Here it fails to match `!\\#\\#` as I have stated that it should not contain !

Invalid inputs - `!A!\\#!A!\\#!A!\\#,  !X, A#A#A#, !a!a!a!a!a`

but unfortunately, it matches `A#A#A#` which is a failure scenario.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: try it on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: Can you explain why `A#A#A#` shouldn't be matched yet `A\\#A\\#A\\#` should? And whether `!\#\#` and `Aaaaa!!` should be matched when you say you stated that "it" should not contain exclamation marks?

Comment: Your regex doesn't seem right as there is an extra `)` at the end which is not balanced. Also the use of `-` in the character set is incorrect and giving error. You need to make sure `-` if used in character set should be either first or last character in it. Also, as per your regex, you seem to be discarding strings starting with `!` character. Can you logically tell what your regex means? What should be a valid and non-valid strings?

Comment: @Aaron - they mean it shouldn't start with an exclamation, not shouldn't contain one.

Comment: @PeterWestlake `!\#\#` also starts with an exclamation mark and is part of the valid samples

Comment: @Aaron, you're right - I missed that one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an unmatched parenthesis at the end of that comment, but otherwise it's just a negative lookahead (so it doesn't start with "!") followed by any number of the characters in the character class. Those include "A" and "#", so any sequences of those characters will be accepted. I don't know what you really want to match, but that's the explanation for why A#A#A# does.